# Logic level issue

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, 3.3v, esp8266

I'm new to electronics so please be patient with my ignorance.

I'm currently dealing with a problem where my primary device deals with 3V logic (Esp8266).

The output from my second device when on is 3.5V and when it is off, it is 2.7v.

How do I build a circuit where it is able to convert 2.7v to logic 0 and 3.5v to logic 1?

Comment: What's your second device?  That's very unusual behavior...  In any case you need a level shifter.  Here are the data/questions you need to know in order to design such a shifter (or just select an off the shelf part that does it for you).  Is the communication bidirectional or unidirectional?  What are the logic thresholds for the two devices (e.g. the highest input that's considered low and the lowest input that's considered high)?  What are the output thresholds (lowest output that's considered high and highest output that's considered low)?

Comment: That info will be very useful in guiding you to a good solution.  I think sparkfun might have a good tutorial on different ways to accomplish what you're after, but suffice it to say there are several solutions ranging from series resistors and diodes to transistors to dedicated ICs that handle everything for you.  http://jamesreubenknowles.com/level-shifting-stragety-experments-1741 has some nice info

Comment: I don't think you are measuring the output form your second device correctly.  No device would intentionally produce those logic levels - what is it?  Please describe things more fully.

Comment: @KevinWhite Actually I worked with a blood glucose meter once that used 2.7 volts for logic 0 and 1.0 volts for logic 1 on its serial interface.  Really.  I used a comparator (like Tom's answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Schmitt trigger circuit using a comparator is probably the best way to go. By adjusting the resistors you can set the high-to-low and low-to-high threshold voltages at the input to be within your 2.7V to 3.5V range. The output would be the full swing of the comparator (e.g. 0 to 5V).

---

The following circuit is an example Schmitt trigger circuit:

[image: Single Rail Schmitt Trigger]

(Circuit image from [here](http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/The_Schmitt_Trigger/?p=1)).

The resistor values are calculated as:

$$R_H = \frac{R_1 \times R_{FB}}{R_1 + R_{FB}} $$
$$V_{thHigh} = \frac{V \times R_2}{R_2 + R_H}$$

$$R_L = \frac{R_2 \times R_{FB}}{R_2 + R_{FB}} $$
$$V_{thLow} = \frac{V \times R_L}{R_1 + R_L}$$

(Equations from [here](http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/The_Schmitt_Trigger/?p=1)).

---

There is a simple calculator [here](http://pcbheaven.com/drcalculus/index.php?calc=st_nonsym_sp) which allows you to determine what resistor values correspond to what threshold voltages.

Based on that and for a +5V supply, an example set of resistors would be:

$$\begin{array} \\
R_1 & = 27 \mathrm{k\Omega} \\
R_2 & = 47 \mathrm{k\Omega} \\
R_{FB} & = 220 \mathrm{k\Omega} \\
\end{array}$$

Would give you thresholds of \$2.9\mathrm{V}\$ and \$3.3\mathrm{V}\$. Reducing \$R_{FB}\$ further would narrow those. For example using \$R_{FB} = 470 \mathrm{k\Omega}\$ would give you thresholds of \$3.06\mathrm{V}\$ and \$3.23\mathrm{V}\$.

---

I've noticed that you said you want a \$+3\mathrm{V}\$ output high level. To accomplish this, you could simply reduce the supply voltage of the comparator to \$+3\mathrm{V}\$ and add a potential divider on the input. If you select the divider so that the voltage at the input is \$3/5\$ of the voltage of your second device, then the above resistor values would still work.